# Check if an array of integers forms a palindrome?

Tags: c++, arrays

So the question requires us to check if the entered elements in an array form a palindrome or not.
For eg, if an array has 134, 21, 12, 431, the output should declare that this is a palindrome.

I tried my best to keep my program simple and the logic used looks right to me. But it still isn't giving me the correct output. For eg, I input the size as 4 and then entered 134, 21, 12, 431. As per my code, I think it should print  "It is a palindrome." but instead there's no ouput on the console.

would be great if somebody can help me with this.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int size;
    cout << "Enter the size of array: " << endl;
    cin >> size;
    int arr[size];
    cout << "Enter the element: " << endl;
    
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    
    int arr2[size/2];
    for (int i=0; i<((size/2)-1); i++)
    {
        int reverse=0; 
        while (arr[i]!=0)
        {   
            int rem; 
            rem = arr[i]%10;
            reverse=((reverse*10)+rem);
            arr[i]=arr[i]/10;
        }
        arr2[i]=reverse; 
    }
    
    for (int i=0; i<((size/2)-1); i++)
    {
        if(arr2[i]==arr[size-1-i])
        {
            if(i==(size/2)-1)
            {
                cout << "It is a palindrome." << endl; 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Array is not a palindrome." << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `12, 34, 5, 4, 32, 1` considered as a palindrome?

Comment: *it still isn't giving me the correct output* When asking for help, always be as specific as possible. Can you give some examples of inputs that work and inputs that fail? Where do you think the problem is? What have you tried so far in debugging the problem?

Comment: I honestly didn't think of this to be a possibility. Now that you've mentioned it, I think I'll have to change my entire code.

Comment: if mikes example is a positive the code can be much simpler

Comment: tip: concatenate the numbers to a string and then check if the full string is a palindrome. That is simpler. (If Mikes examples is not a positive then you can add `,` between the numbers in the string)

Answer (score -2):

You can check whether the count of non-repeated couples is 1 or 0.

```
 bool isPalindrome(std::vector<int>& vec) {
        int max = *(std::max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end()));
        std::vector<int> tmp(max + 1, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
            ++tmp[vec[i]];
        }
        int odd = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.size(); ++i) {
            if (tmp[i] % 2 == 1) {
                ++odd;
            }
        } 
        return (odd == 1 || odd == 0);
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).